# I am trying to implement some logic on real time order sync using scheduler

Tags: actions, events, scheduled-posts

I am trying to call a function using the scheduler, `wp_schedule_single_event`, it is successfully scheduled but the function related to the hook is not called.

Comment: Can you share the code what you have tried and what are the things you try to achive ?

Comment: If the arguments are incorrect or in the wrong format then it won't run.  Anything in the debug.log?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.